# Buttons/Operations to Run Android App in VM

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I am attempting to launch/run my Android app on the Xamarin Android Player through Visual Studio. Literally what buttons/operations do you perform the send the app to the currently running emulator in Visual Studio 2013?

I have successfully setup the virtual machines (Android Kitkat) IP address through the ADB console and have confirmed that ADB is finding this connected device. Note when open the AVD Manager my VM isn't listed. Maybe because the VM was created in Xamarin Android Player?

How do I send the app to the VM? Do I right click my Android project and select deploy? Doing this outputs an error:

> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The debugging section should look something like this (the deploy/start debugging button is the button with the Play symbol):
[image]

The first thing to do is make sure you have your Xamarin Android project set as the startup project (Right click project -> Set as startup project).

After that, if you click the dropdown arrow on the `Start Debugging` (button with play symbol) button, you should see your XAP VM listed there. It should be the same name as when you chose which XAP VM to start, for example, I selected this VM to start in XAP:
[image]

If you don't see your VM in the drop down, Visual Studio is not connecting to XAP properly.

If you do see the VM, select it, and then click the `Start Debugging` button to run your app on the VM.